# Fill missing values using a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, fillna

Here is my sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[3, np.nan, np.nan],[5, np.nan, np.nan]], index=['country1', 'country2'], columns=[2021, 2022, 2023])
```

Here is my sample dictionary:

```
d = {'country1': {'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'assumed','key3': {2022: '10', 2023: ' 20'}}, 'country2': {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'assumed', 'key3': {2022: '30', 2023: ' 40'}}}
```

I am aiming to use the dictionary d to replace the missing values in the dataframe df. I thought I'd use something like:

```
df.fillna(d2)
```

where d2 is a dictionary based on dictionary d:

```
d2 = {'country1': {2022: '10', 2023: ' 20'}, 'country2': {2022: '30', 2023: ' 40'}}
```

I don't know how to generate d2 but it doesn't work anyway.

The result would look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[[3, 10, 20],[5, 30, 40]], index=['country1', 'country2'], columns=[2021, 2022, 2023])
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please provide your desired final output.

Comment: @OD1995 I have added the expected result, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can still use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) but before that we have to normalize/transform the dictionary in a format which is suitable for `fillna`

```
df.T.fillna({k: v['key3'] for k, v in d.items()}).T
```

Result

```
         2021 2022 2023
country1  3.0   10   20
country2  5.0   30   40
```

Comment: Thanks! My df in real life has a multi-index with two levels. Level 0 is the continent and level 1 is the country. How do I change your solution for it to work with my real-life df? At the moment it's failing. I need fillna to disregard level 0 of the index, but I'd like to keep level 0 in the solution.

Comment: I have solved it with an intermediate step where I get rid of the index level 0 and apply your solution to create a temporary fill_values dataframe, which I then pass to df.fillna(value=fill_values). If you have a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: @ric Glad to help. I guess you have already figured out the solution that is the way to go. But anyways I'll let you know if there is a better way..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `df.fillna(d2)`, it looks like the best way of achieving this would be the following:

```
for country,country_dict in d.items():
    for year,value in country_dict['key3'].items():
        df.loc[country,year] = value
```